# jQuery not(), ignoring certain named elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

hope you can help me!

I have a form, which has a large amount of `inputs`.  These inputs have the initial class of `inputLight`, which uses light grey text.  I have the following jQuery code to, on `focus` change the colour of text to `inputDark`, and on `blur` to change it back:

```
$('input').focus(function(){
$(this).attr('class', 'inputDark');})
.blur(function() {$(this).attr('class', 'inputLight');
```

This absolutely works.  I also have the following code to delete the value of an `input` when it is first selected.

```
/* First time only, delete default text*/
$('input').one('focus', function(){
$(this).val('');});
```

That works too.  Where am I going with this? Well, I have two `input` buttons, one for submitting the form and one for clearing it - but my problem lies not with validation.

When the user clicks either button, it of course, deletes it's value.  And changes the colour of the text.

I don't want either event to happen to these buttons, which are named `Submit Button` and `Clear Button`.

I tried using:

```
/* Toggle gray/black text */
$('input').not('input[name=Submit Button]').not('input[name=Clear Button]').focus(function()     {$(this).attr('class', 'inputDark');}).blur(function() {$(this).attr('class', 'inputLight');   });
```

and:

```
/* First time only, delete default text*/
$('input').not('input[name=Submit Button]').not('input[name=Clear Button]').one('focus', function(){
$(this).val('');
});
```

Sorry for the bad markup there, I know it must look terrible.

With the `.not()` functions in there, neither function works, but the buttons work.  Take out `.not()` and the effects work, but the buttons go haywire.

Can anyone help me here?

Comment: Why can't I edit the post?  I try editing it and nothing happens...? And the phrase 'Hi guys' get's deleted...sorry if the post sounds rude, but I swear I had 'hi guys' in the first line... :(

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it.  Your post doesn't sound rude.

Comment: `@Joseph`, Thanks, I'm really self-concious of how my questions come across...:D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wouldn't `$('input:text')` be more productive?

```
$('input:text').focus(function(){
$(this).attr('class', 'inputDark');})
.blur(function() {$(this).attr('class', 'inputLight');

/* First time only, delete default text*/
$('input:text').one('focus', function(){
$(this).val('');});
```

Comment: xD. Wow, I'm new to `jQuery` and totally forgot you could do that...I'll check to see if it works.

Comment: You sir, are a genius! That works wonders! Now if you could just get me back the last hour of my life, I would be most appreciative, lol! :D  Thanks again, you've got my tick once the 10 minutes rolls by!

Comment: lol no problem :) glad to help... (though I think time travel is a stretch XD)